# CreateToolhelp32Snapshot fails when enumerating a 32bit process from a 32 bit process

Tags: c++, winapi

I am writing a basic debugger in c++.  I am trying to get a list of the loaded modules of the debugged process from the debugger process.  My OS is 64bit windows 7, but both the debugger and the debuggee are compiled 32 bit (when looked at in task manager, they have *32 next to their names).

Whenever I try to call CreateToolhelpSnapshot on the debuggee from the debugger, I get a 299 error.  MSDN says that this should only happen if querying a 64 bit process from a 32 bit on or vice versa.  Both of my processes are 32 bit as far as I can tell.

Here is my snapshot code:

```
HANDLE hModuleSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, pid);
if( hModuleSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
{
    std::cout << "CreateToolhelp32Snapshot Error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Debuggers should use `LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT` to learn what modules are loaded in a process.

Comment: Are you SURE you have the correct Process ID to start with? How are you retrieving the `pid` value?

Comment: I am using LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT to detect loaded modules, however sometimes I cannot resolve the module name at load time.  Listing the modules through snapshot was an attempt to see if I could get module names for unresolved dlls.  I did confirm that I have the correct pid, I am keeping an instance of it from when the process is  created/attached to.

Comment: And still the problems occur.... In my case, there is a "twist"... I need the snapshot (cant use the LOAD_DLL event to gather as I am in a debugger and need to enumerate the threads of the process with Thread32First - which needs an actual snapshot...

Answer (score 0):

Use `TH32CS_SNAPMODULE` instead of `TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32`.

Another cause may be that the process that you want to enumerate is just starting up and is not yet ready with loading it's modules. So what I do is calling `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` in a loop and when getting error `ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY` (299) I wait a 200 milliseconds and then try again to enumerate the modules until I don't get this error anymore.

If this does not work for you will have to use another API to enumerate the modules. Have a look at this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19685/Get-Process-Info-with-NtQueryInformationProcess

The `PEB_LDR_DATA` structure contains information about the loaded modules for the process.

More details here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa813708.aspx

EDIT:
I found a case where the above does not solve the problem. I finally found that enumerating modules in a 64 bit process works only correctly if CreateToolHelpSnapshot is running also in a 64 bit process. A shame that Microsoft implemented this so buggy.

Comment: bad answer... I'm just sitting here already using `TH32CS_SNAPMODULE`, and your answer did nothing to solve the problem.

Comment: I modified my answer.